# django.contrib.comments 'not synced' after adding it to installed_apps

Tags: django, django-south

I want to replace a home-made comment object by a proxy of django.contrib.comments.models.Comment.

I modified my comments/models.py, added django.contrib.comments to my installed_apps and set COMMENTS_APPS to my comment app's name.

When running python manage.py syncdb (I use South), I get 'django.contrib.comments' in the 'not synced' apps, so the corresponding tables are not created.

How can I get the tables related to django.contrib.comments to be created?

thanks

Julien

Comment: Does the comments app you're using have any migrations (possibly created by someone else) which means it would be treated as a South app to migrate, not a syncdb app? e

Comment: Yes, it does. But shouldn't the django.contrib.comments table created anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember well, there was a name conflict between my Comment and Django Comment...

Answer (score 1):

Table creation is under south (schema) versioning scheme as usual.

Use either `manage.py migrate` or just always run `manage.py syncdb --migrate` .